# f:translate not working in one action

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I've a extension with two Actions: `listAction` and `filterAction`.

For both Actions I'm using `f:translate` referring to the translation. Both Actions are included on the same page.

Now comes the fun part. `listAction` is translating, `filterAction` not. `filterAction` is only showing the default text, while the `listAction` is switching the language properly.

The default action comes from an .xlf File, the second language is configured by typoscript.

I am literally trying to find a solution the whole day now, but without success.

Is this a known 7.6 LTS Problem or could there any misconfiguration?

Comment: Please provide more of your configuration. "The second language is configured by TypoScript" is unclear. Post examples of TS, XLIFF and Fluid so we can help.

Comment: Did you clear caches (from the install tool) after changing the label?

Comment: Yes. TYPO3 Cache and the Install Tool Cache. I've even deleted the temp folder to be sure. The strange thing is, I am able to use the same label in the listAction and it works.